# Searching the registry and i need the output of Path from list of servers using VBscript

Tags: windows, vbscript, for-loop

Below Script is working fine ,it gets the path of the key i am searching . Please some one help me to find the way to read the list of servers from text file. im learning vbscript and tried some ways to read the text file it fails.

```
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
strComputer = "Server name" 
const REG_SZ = 1 
const REG_EXPAND_SZ = 2 
const REG_BINARY = 3 
const REG_DWORD = 4 
const REG_MULTI_SZ = 7 
strOriginalKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\VMware, Inc.\VMware Tools" 
FindKeyValue(strOriginalKeyPath) 
'------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Function FindKeyValue(strKeyPath) 
    Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &_        
          strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv") 
    errorCheck = oReg.EnumKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrSubKeys)        

    If (errorCheck=0 and IsArray(arrSubKeys)) then        
          For Each subkey In arrSubKeys            
          strNewKeyPath = strKeyPath & "\" & subkey            
          FindKeyValue(strNewKeyPath)        
          Next    
    End If 
oReg.EnumValues HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, _            
          arrValueNames, arrValueTypes     
If (errorCheck=0 and IsArray(arrValueNames)) then        
           For i=0 To UBound(arrValueNames)            
          'Wscript.Echo "Value Name: " & arrValueNames(i)        
 if arrValueNames(i) = "InstallPath" then            
          strValueName = arrValueNames(i)            
          oReg.GetDWORDValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strValueName, dwValue            
          wscript.echo strComputer & "\" & strkeyPath & vbNewLine              
  end if        
  Next    
End if 
end Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is some code I use to read a list of machine names like:

```
MACHINE1
MACHINE2
MACHINE3
```

Into an array, which you can then loop through with a "For" statement.

```
pcList = readlist("C:\temp\testlist.txt")

'
' Reads in a list of PC names from a file and returns
' an array containing one PC name per member.
'
' Blank lines are ignored.
' Lines starting with ";" are treated as comments and
' are not added to the list.
'
'
function ReadList(listfile)

   const forReading = 1

   dim thelist()
   redim thelist(1)
   listLen = 0

   set theFSO = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   set listFile = theFSo.openTextFile(listfile,forReading)

   while not listFile.atendofstream

     pcname = ltrim(rtrim(listFile.readline))

     if len(pcname)>1 and left(pcname,1)<>";" then

        if listlen = 0 then
           thelist(0) = pcname
           listlen = listlen+1
        else
           redim preserve thelist(listlen)
           thelist(listlen) = pcname
           listlen = listlen + 1
        end if


     end if

   wend

   listfile.close
   set listfile = nothing
   set thefso = nothing

   ReadList = theList

end Function
```